# Apache web server: AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest with FallbackResource

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

When I use "FallbackResource" in my apache 2.4 web server config, it shows the error "AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels"..

Please some help on how to solve this.
Is specify the url "http://localhost/bv-host/plusRoot/plus/fiets" and want it to be forwarded to the default index.html: "/bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html"

I enabled the debug logging. Mode-rewrite is disabled. If I remove the FallbackResource line, I don't see this error but rather an excepted 404 error.

I have a default 2.4 installation on my mac with the following config added:

```
FallbackResource /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
Alias /bv-host/plusRoot "/Users/ed/Develop/Projecten/Web”
```

That's it, the debug logging snippet:

```
[client ::1:57840] mod_hfs_apple: Allowing access with matching directory. filename = /Users/ed/Develop/Projecten/Web/plus/index.html;
AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[client ::1:57840] AH00121: r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/index.html;
[client ::1:57840] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /bv-host/plusRoot/plus/fiets
```

Answer (score 20):

Note that you can also get this error if your FallbackResource path isn't absolute. For example:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

will fail on any second level request: /foo/bar will fail because it will try to fallback to /foo/index.php. So you need to specify the root:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: I feel that this is the right solution to the question posed. This avoid going in loop. Thanks.

Comment: This solution was a life saver. Was exactly the problem.

Comment: I had `./index.html`. Changing to `/index.html` seems to have resolved the issue

Answer (score 5):

I've been on a similar trouble setting up a Silex application in a subfolder. I was using just a `FallbackResource index.php` with your same results.

Ended up using the classic Rewrite exampple.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /path/to/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too and found a solution.

In my case, this happened because the page requested a resource (it was a css file) which was not placed in the good directory.

```
<link href="somewhere_bad_directory/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then the FallbackResource was called ten times and did not provide the resource, hence the error.

Solution : when using "FallbackResource" in a directory, if you have this error "AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels", inspect carefully your page for misplaced resources.